# Magento 2.4.2 invalid header value detected in laminas-http module GenericHeader.php

Tags: magento, laminas

I installed Magento 2.4.2 on XAMPP server on my localhost by

1. downloading using Composer and
2. running php bin/magento setup:install
3. after the installation I run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   Now when I try to run Magento from localhost/magento242/pub directory I get this error related to laminas plugin
   Laminas\Http\Header\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid header value detected in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento242\vendor\laminas\laminas-http\src\Header\GenericHeader.php:54

I have no idea  what's causing the error. any help?

Comment: [RensWolters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16047421) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68561701) saying "Can you check your base url? I think you have an invalid character like a space in the url."

Comment: I have checked and my base url is fine. It seems to me that the error occurs when  laminas parses the url but can't figure why and when.

Comment: facing same issue, can you update the fix ?

Answer (score -1):

Since others are facing the same problem, I circumvented (solved) the problem by avoiding to use Composer download and downloaded  the zip file from Magento and problem was gone.